# wordpress wp_include_post() in custom post with coustom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I'm new in WordPress and my English are not good. I'm using [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin to create a post type **Product** and [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin to create some custom fields like address. Now I'm reading XML file (title, description, price, brand etc) with 3000 products and save all in my custom database. While reading and save it in database I want to create post like product where name is title, slug is title (can I create a category by brands or `PARENTpage` from other custom field?) description etc. With `wp_insert_post()` how can I insert `$variable` in custom field? I want something like

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $row['product_name'],
  'post_content'  => $row['description'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_name'      => $row['product_name'],
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_type'     => 'product',
  'custom_field_brand'         => $row['brand'], 
  'custom_field_price'         => $row['price']
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced Custom Fields saves the post meta a little differently. WHat you have to do here is instead of including the post meta in the wp_insert_post after

```
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

returns the ID of the post created.

Use the Post ID with the acf function [update_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) to update the post meta like this

```
update_field( custom_field, custom_field_data, $post_id );
```